# How to add defined environment variable to a .service file

Tags: services, environment-variables, tomcat

I'm installing Tomcat and one of the last steps requires to define a .service file for it.
In that file I must define a line with

```
Environment="JAVA_HOME=path_to_java"
```

I already have a JAVA_HOME environment variable defined, is there any way of point to it from the .service file? Something like:

```
Environment="JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A systemd service file is not interpreted by the shell (be it `sh`or `bash`), so you need to be explicit in such system files and specify the literal value. Especially for system wide services, any of your environmental variables may not even be defined yet when it is run.